# ¿Es posible hacer consultar un archivo con Laravel?

Tags: laravel

¿Podría consultar si existe un archivo en mi directorio storage? requiero hacer un condicional

```
@if(archivo existe)
   Mostralo
@endif
```

Esto no funciona, pero algo así

```
@if(asset('storage/media/products/'.$product['reference'].'-05.png'))
```

Comment: yo lo que hago en un sistema es guardar en base de datos la ruta del archivo cuando lo guardo en el sistema, luego consulto por la ruta si existe o si ese campo no esta vació de la base de datos, quizás te sirve algo similar.

Comment: ese codigo parece de blade, no? creo que se puede utilizar file_exists en el if de blade... echa un vistazo a la doc de blade

Comment: @Jakala muchísimas gracias! me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: @NicolasRudisky Gracias, intenté primero con la opción de Jakala que era era la opción más simpley me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Como lo indicó el amigo Jakala, con `file_exists` se soluciona el problema a mí duda.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Agrego al coentario anterior, que sería util algo más espicífico. Cuál es el código que usaste  y pir qué?